# wiring two thermostats in parallel

Tags: thermostat

I wqant to add a wifi thermostat to a millivolt system. I would like to keep the current thermostat in case of power lost so that it would kick in at a minimum temp say 45 degrees. How do you wire a thermostat in parallel? Thanks

Comment: If i read the wifi thermostat directions it says all the battery does is keep it from loosing the settings and does not operate the thermostat. I have a vented heater with no electric to it which will operate if the power would go off. So my concern is if power goes off and the wifi thermostat does not work to statrt heater i need a backup thermostat to start the heater. I have a Honeywell wifi thermostat. Thanks

Comment: How would the other thermostat work in case of power loss? If there's no power, your furnace won't kick in.

Comment: Its a millivolt thermostat that controls a vented heater. No power to the heater just the pilot

Answer (score 2):

First of all, most if not all "wifi" thermostats have a battery backup so the thermostat keeps working even if the wifi goes down.

Second, if you lose power, how do you expect your furnace to keep running?  Your existing thermostat runs on electricity too.

Comment: In a millivolt system -- the electricity for the thermostat and gas valve is generated by the furnace itselsf

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not familiar w/ this-- so if the furnace shuts down, is there built-in battery backup?

Comment: The thermopile that generates the power for the 'stat and gas valve sits in the pilot flame -- that way, the only way it'd shut off is if the pilot blew out, which should shut down the whole show *anyway* to avoid KABOOM.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  ahhh...   I'm more accustomed to non-pilot systems which depend on a spark to ignite :-)